# What kernel to select when using LIBSVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am current performing classification of two labels using libsvm in matlab. I have extracted the features and there are about 69 of them. I just want to know if it is alright to use linear kernel for two-class classification that has around 69 features.

Thanks

Marcus

Comment: more details are needed. At least: number of training examples, number of positive and negatove examples

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly fine. I've used linear kernels for data that had about 5000 features. (Not saying this was the best way to go, but it's possible.)

Better yet, why not just try the RBF kernel as well and compare the results?

Comment: @D Seita in ML you can use any algorithm you want - you will always get some result. Then the question is whether the results are correct(e.g. task that achieved high accuracy look like good results but if its precision is 0% - then the result is bad!). So data analyses/preparation before applying ML is crucial and according this analyses you can try to guess ehat ML algorithm to choose...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the situation. In different scenarios, the result will be different for different kernels. You need to try.

Give a try for RBF kernel, polynomial kernel. Different kernels give different results. You got to try.

Answer (score 1):

It always depends on the nature of your data. If it is linearly separable then a linear kernel is more than enough.

If the data is non linear and locally encapsulated (in other words, if there exists an hyper sphere that would enclosure all the data - new points included), then a RBF kernel sounds like the proper kernel for the job.

If the data is non linear but it is not encapsulated ( so it might always be a new point far from your training set data) then you might want to try with a continuous kernel such as a polynomial one)

It is hard to deduce the nature of your data in high dimensional spaces, so most of the time the practical solution is try different scenarios and use crossvalidation to pick the proper kernel and parameters.

However, sometimes plotting different pairs of features helped me to have an idea about my data nature, but it is just a very rough indicator.